# IfEqual always evaluating to False (AutoHotKeys)

Tags: if-statement, colors, compare, equals, autohotkey

I have two methods which I'm using to get and compare two colors. The first is to get the color

```
/*
This function returns the color at the given coordinates in hexadecimal format 
*/
GetColor(x, y) {
    MouseMove x, y
    PixelGetColor, colorToReturn, x, y
    Return %colorToReturn%
}
```

And here is my check color method

```
/*
This function checks the passed color with the color at 600, 475.
*/
CheckColor(colorToCheck) {
    colorToCompare := GetColor(600, 475)
    MsgBox %colorToCheck% - %colorToCompare%
    IfEqual %colorToCheck%, %colorToCompare%, Return, 1
    Return 0
}
```

I call it with this hotkey but I always get 0 back even though the two colors are the same color.

```
^t:: ; CTRL + T test color compare
colorToTest := GetColor(600, 475)
result := CheckColor(colorToTest)
MsgBox %result%
RETURN
```

Why does my check color always return false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfEqual.htm

`IfEqual, var, value`

> `var` - The variable name.
>
> `value` - A literal string, number, or variable reference (e.g.
>   %var2%).

So if you are set on using `IfEqual` command instead of `if (expression)` it should look like that:

```
IfEqual, colorToCheck, %colorToCompare%,Return 1
```

[`if (expression)`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) altrenative:

```
if (colorToCheck=colorToCompare)
Return 1
```

Comment: You've been faster and preciser (+1).

Answer (score 1):

"IfEqual %colorToCheck%, %colorToCompare%, Return, 1"

should be

```
IfEqual colorToCheck, %colorToCompare%, Return, 1
```

Variable names in an **[expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions)** are not enclosed in percent signs (except for pseudo-arrays and other double references).

If a **[variable](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ref)** is enclosed in percent signs within an expression (e.g. %Var%), whatever that variable contains is assumed to be the name or partial name of another variable (if there is no such variable, %Var% resolves to a blank string).

Comment: Wow, I could have sworn I tried that, but I must have forgotten to reload the script. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately Bob's answer is more precise so i have to give it to him but ill upvote you